# How do I save the result of a MySQL query as a Windows CMD variable

Tags: mysql, cmd

I want to use the windows command line to create an HTML file containing a single HTML table from a MySQL query

I can write an HTML file using the echo command

```
echo <html> <head> <title> </title> </head>  <body>...</body> >mywebpage.html
```

The Table data results from an SQL query and needs to be declared as a JSON object in the HTML file

How can I save the SQL output as a CMD array and how do I iterate through this array.

My Windows Scipt so far

```
CD C:\MySQL\..\bin
mysql -u usernae p
mypassword
use myDatabase
SELECT BLA, BLA, SUM(CASE WHEN IF BUT BLA..) FROM BLA GROUP BY BLA ..
```

How do I save the result of the sql statement as a CMD variable/array so that I can iterate through each "cell" in it and declare the same as JSON object in the HTML file ?

I am an accountant trying to show the CFO that automation need not mean a $100,000 project. Can't use PHP/Python because I not allowed to. I am only allowed CMD.

Comment: This should get you started: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/13/using-awk-to-convert-mysql-output-to-tables/ just translate it to Windows.

Comment: Your echo command will **not** create HTML.  You need to escape all the angle brackets.